# Was there an actual masque in 'The Masque of Mandragora'?

Tags: doctor-who

*The Masque of Mandagora* was a story featuring the Fourth Doctor and set in fictional city of San Martino in 15th Century Italy.

A [masque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masque) is not a mask that one puts over one's face, but a kind of dance or pageant. Was there such a scene in this story?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at the end of episode four (or rather [part four](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Masque_of_Mandragora_(TV_story))) of the story arc, we see the masqued ball that the characters have been talking about for most of the previous three shows.

[image]

At the same time the Doctor is facing off against a masked figure.

[image]